# Normalization for different color spaces for ResNet

Tags: image, pytorch, normalization, color-space, pytorch-dataloader

I am implementing the application of a ResNet neural network across different color spaces.

I apply masks to the training images that delineate the area to be left for the network to learn.

The question is whether applying conversion to a different color space for an already normalized RGB image is ok? For example, normalized RGB image convert to HSV and then pass it to CNN.

Should I first subject the image to conversion and then normalization?

I am using that method for calculate mean and std for my dataset:
https://www.binarystudy.com/2021/04/how-to-calculate-mean-standard-deviation-images-pytorch.html

Can I use this method to calculate values for normalization in other color spaces?

The other color spaces I'm using are HSV, HSL, YUV, LAB, YCrCb, etc.

I am implementing the application of a ResNet neural network across different color spaces.

I apply masks to the training images that delineate the area to be left for the network to learn.

The question is whether applying conversion to a different color space for an already normalized RGB image is ok? For example, normalized RGB image convert to HSV and then pass it to CNN.

Should I first subject the image to conversion and then normalization?

I am using that method for calculate mean and std for my dataset:
https://www.binarystudy.com/2021/04/how-to-calculate-mean-standard-deviation-images-pytorch.html

Can I use this method to calculate values for normalization in other color spaces?

The other color spaces I'm using are HSV, HSL, YUV, LAB, YCrCb, etc.